# Test Class for Adding Attachments to a Case File Before Closing

Tags: trigger, unit-test, case

I have an apex class that throws an error on a case when a rep tries to close and save the case if there is no attachment or chatter file attached to it. I have the class working but my test class is only covering 53% of the code. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong in the test class? Thanks!

Apex Class

```
trigger SFDCtest on Case (before update) {
  Map<Id,Case> caseAttachments = new Map<Id,Case>(
    [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Attachments) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]
  );
  List<FeedItem> FIsToInsert = new List<FeedItem>();
  boolean myval = True;

  for (FeedItem f : [select id, type, RelatedRecordId, parentId, title, body from FeedItem where parentid in :Trigger.new and type = 'ContentPost'])
 //the area below is not covered
 {
                   // Verify fields that we cannot use to filter SOQL
                if (f.RelatedRecordId != null)  {
                     myval  = false;
                }
  //the area above is not covered

 }

  for(Case cs:Trigger.new) {

       if(cs.Case_Problem_Code_1__c == null) {
        //trigger should not fire
    }


    else if((cs.Status=='Closed') && (cs.Case_Problem_Code_1__c.contains('A29') || cs.Case_Problem_Code_1__c.contains('A28')) &&// If it is changing to closed/won...
   //the area below is not covered   
   (!caseAttachments.containsKey(cs.id) || // And the case was not found (Insert)...
       caseAttachments.get(cs.id).Attachments == null || // Or the case attachment list was null...
       caseAttachments.get(cs.id).Attachments.size()==0) && myval  )



       { // Or the attachment list has no entries...

      cs.Status.addError('You must first attach a file to this case before changing to Closed.'); // So we prevent saving here.
      }
      //the area above is not covered
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest 
public class CaseEmailSendTriggerTest {

static testMethod void testAttachments() { 
    Account a = new Account(name='Test');
    insert a;

    Case cse=new Case(Case_Problem_Code_1__c= 'In Service Billable - A29', accountid=a.id); 
    insert cse; 

    Attachment attach=new Attachment(); 
    attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment'; 
    Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body'); 
    attach.body=bodyBlob; attach.parentId=cse.id;
    insert attach;

    List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:cse.id]; 
    System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size()); 

    Test.StartTest();
    FeedItem f = new FeedItem();
        f.ParentId = cse.id;
        f.body = 'test';
        insert f;
        FeedComment fc = new FeedComment();
        fc.CommentBody = 'legal test';
        fc.FeedItemId = f.Id;   // please add this
        insert fc;
        Test.StopTest();
        System.assertEquals ('legal test', fc.commentbody); 



    }

}
```

Comment: You'll find that people will be more willing to spend time helping you with these kinds of problems if you tell them which lines of code aren't covered by your test class (hint: knowing the line number isn't helpful since we can't tell the number when viewing it here, so mark you code sections).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have marked which areas are not covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting coverage because you aren't causing your `SFDCTest` trigger (on Case) to fire again after you've inserted the rest of your test data (Attachment and FeedItem). Right now, your test method is acting like a negative case for most of your trigger. (i.e. testing that your trigger doesn't do work under your test conditions)

To get your coverage on this particular test, you'd only need to add the following sometime after you insert your FeedItem:

```
cse.Status = 'Closed';
Update cse;
```

It's also good to keep in mind that good unit test classes will test both positive and negative cases, and not just aim for coverage alone. If you don't already have test methods for verifying the behavior when there isn't an Attachment/FeedItem, I'd suggest adding those tests as well so you verify when you won't see the error on the Status field.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF! I added the two lines above and I also added a negative case where there were no attachments added. I really appreciate the advice :)